# Multiple relations and MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm currently working on a databank project with mysql and php where one particular query is giving me an enormous headache.

In this project we have to search subcontractors for skills like java, c++ etc and evaluate if their skill rating is equal or grater to the rating value asked for.

We have a database scheme which looks something like that:

table subs:

- sub_id
- sub_region_id

table regions:

- region_id
- region_name

table skills:

- skill_id
- skill_name

table skillratings:

- skillrating_id
- skillrating_value

table subtoskill:

- subtoskill_id
- subtoskill_sub_id
- subtoskill_skill_id
- subtoskill_raitng_id

The subtoskill Table holds the N*N relations of subcontractors to skills,
so an entry with "1, 2, 3, 4" would state that the subcontractor with id 2
has the skill with id 3 and the rating with id 4.

Now I want to query multiple skills with an AND or OR connection,
for example "which subcontractors have skill java with value>=2 AND c++ with value>=4".

The OR query works perfectly(code below) but the AND query gives 0 results,
except if the same skill with different values is picked.

```
/*
 * selectSubsBySkill
 * search database for subcontractors with given skills and ratings
 * parameter:
 * -$skill_ids array of ids(int) of skills, same size as $ratings
 * -$ratings array of rating values(int) for skills, same size as $skill_ids
 * -$and boolean true if and connection, else or connection of skills
 * return:
 * array with matching subcontractors information
 */
public function selectSubsBySkill($skill_ids, $ratings, $and){
    if(empty($skill_ids)){
        return $this->selectSubs();
    }
    $sel = 'SELECT * FROM '.SUBS.','.REGIONS.','.SKILLS.','.SUBTOSKILL.','.SKILLRATINGS.' WHERE '.
        SUB_REGION_ID.'='.REGION_ID.' AND '.SUBTOSKILL_SUB_ID.'='.SUB_ID.' AND '.
    SUBTOSKILL_SKILL_ID.'='.SKILL_ID.' AND '.SKILLRATING_ID.'='.SUBTOSKILL_RATING_ID.' AND (';

    $i=0;
    foreach($skill_ids as $skill_id){
        $sel .= '('.SKILLRATING_VALUE.'>='.$ratings[$i].' AND '.SUBTOSKILL_SKILL_ID.'='.$skill_id.')';
        if($i<sizeof($skill_ids)-1){
            if($and)$sel .= ' AND ';
            else $sel .= ' OR ';
        }
        $i++;
    }       
    $sel .= ') GROUP BY '.SUB_ID;
    return $this->query($sel);
}
```

I've tried several other examples including queries with UNIONs or JOINs but still nothing has worked.

I'd be glad if someone here got a hint to solve this problem.

Comment: seems like the whole db structure is off to me can you tell me your requirements so ill draw an er for you 
i came to this conclusion because the n2n table has an id it needs to be composite 
it looks like someone over normalized this to the point where its not normalized its broken relations

Comment: Have you considered using a bit mask technique, representing each skill as a unique binary value, and maintaining a bit mask value to represent the combination of skills for a user, then using bit-wise operations to determine if a particular skill is in the mask (skill_bits & skill_id ) = skill_id

Comment: @udog would be a nice idea if I'd only have to check if a subcontractor has a skill but I also have to know if his skillrating is equal or higher to the given one

Comment: @Buddhi741 the subtoskill_id is only for internal identification, so updating a subcontrators skill is easier. I don't see how this is over normalized as it's the classical N2N relation table. Futher more the OR querry works perfectly so I can't se why the relation should be broken.
Requirements:
-subcontractors have 0 to N skills (and 1 region)
-every associated skill has a rating(1-5 atm) to show how well the subcontractor is at this skill